# Mysql LIMIT not limiting my query

Tags: mysql, limit

Why the following query return records from 32 - 54 instead of its specified in LIMIT clause?

```
SELECT
    info.*,
    type.titulo AS type_name,
    category.titulo AS category_name
FROM infos_infos info
LEFT JOIN infos_categories category
    ON category.id=info.category
LEFT JOIN infos_canais type
   ON type.id=info.type
WHERE
    info.active=1 AND
    type.active=1
GROUP BY info.id
LIMIT 32,48
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) it says:

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement.
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

So what you want it so set `LIMIT` like

```
LIMIT 32, 16 # this will return rows from 32 - 48
```

To answer your question "Why the following query return records from 32 - 54?" It's because you set start at 32 and you do not have more then 54 items. That is why. The `LIMIT 32,48` will try to show rows from 32 - 80!

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

LIMIT as you use it is a OFFSET + Count , you probably have less than 80 (32+48) result, so it shows you from offset 32 till end of your data

```
SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
```

Comment: @caramba beat me to it :) - should I delete?

Comment: Leave it if you want to keep the 10 points. I would appreciate your upvote.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Should be:

```
SELECT
        info.*,
        type.titulo AS type_name,
        category.titulo AS category_name
    FROM infos_infos info
    LEFT JOIN infos_categories category
        ON category.id=info.category
    LEFT JOIN infos_canais type
       ON type.id=info.type
    WHERE
        info.active=1 AND
        type.active=1
    GROUP BY info.id
    LIMIT 32,16
```

Comment: this will give 32+22 = 32 to 54 - not 32 to  48 as wanted